# AngularJS com md.data.table handler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Tenho uma aplicação com [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) utilizando [Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) e [md.data.table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) na ultima versão de cada Framework(respectivamente 1.6.4, 1.1.0 e 0.10.x). Na documentação do [md.data.table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) é possível verificar que existe uma função de callback quando um item da tabela é selecionado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Porém, ao utilizar essa função em meus scripts, sempre ocorre que nunca essa função é chamada apenas uma vez. Ela é invocada quando a tabela é carregada, quando seleciono um item(o que era para ocorrer apenas UMA vez, porém ele dispara umas 150 chamadas simultâneas o que, para meu código, não deveria acontecer), já tentei de n maneirar contornar este problema e resolvi pedir ajuda. Abaixo segue um teste que fiz com um log de console.

**Código**

`vm.onMainFlowSelected = (flow) => {console.log('executado');}`

**Print Scren**

A tela acabou de carregar e NADA está selecionado, porém
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Console**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foram executados 80 vezes, somente no carregar da página.

Só para não restar dúvidas, aqui está minha directiva em [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

```
<tr 
md-row md-select="flow" 
md-select-id="flow.id" 
md-auto-select 
md-on-select="onSelectItem(flow)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que era.

Em

```
<tr 
md-row md-select="flow" 
md-select-id="flow.id" 
md-auto-select 
md-on-select="onSelectItem(flow)">
```

Quando passo a função para a view, ela pega em referência e eu estava utilizando () quando na verdade deveria apenas passar o metodo. Sendo assim, para resolver necessito apenas remover os () da tag md-on-select, ficando assim:

```
<tr 
md-row md-select="flow" 
md-select-id="flow.id" 
md-auto-select 
md-on-select="onSelectItem">
```

Agradeço.